# Python: Como importar corretamente um método que depende de outro?

Tags: python, método, importação

Eu estou no reinício de um projeto que eu fiz em Java, buscando aprender sobre o Python em POO, mas estou preso numa coisa que ainda não achei qualquer solução:

Eu tenho 2 arquivos ("trabalhando.py" e "arquivos.py").

O 2º é responsável por quaisquer serviços relacionados a arquivo (escrita, testes, leitura...), tudo bonitinho dentro de uma classe de nome Arquivos.

Mas quando tento importar de alguma forma que funcione recebo um erro de alguma função que não foi definida. Sendo que a *esmagadora maioria das funções dentro de arquivos.py depende de uma função de nome existe(nome)*.

**trabalhando.py:**

```
"""==========
  trabalhando.py
=========="""
from arquivos import Arquivos

a = Arquivos()
print(a.le("banco.txt")) #Uma lista do tamanho da qtd de linhas
```

**arquivos.py:**

```
"""==========
  arquivos.py
=========="""
class Arquivos:
    #testes
    def existe (nome): 
        try: 
            with open(nome, "r") as arquivo:
                pass 
        except IOError: 
            return (nome, "w")

        arquivo.close
        return (nome, "a")

    #leitura de arquivo
    def le (arquivo):
        objeto = existe(arquivo)  ##<= linha problema
        if (objeto == (arquivo, "w")):
            return []

        file = open(objeto[0], "r")
        texto = []

        for i in file:
            if (i == "\n"):
                continue
            texto.insert(len(texto), i[:i.index("\n")])
            if (len(texto)%136 == 0):
                print(aguarde(len(texto)))

        file.close
        return texto
```

Então, como é que eu faço pra chamar a função le(arquivo) de arquivos.py sem ele me indicar problema de **"existe não está definido"**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Funções dentro de classes são chamadas de métodos , e eles devem ter como primeiro parâmetro o valor `self` e após ele o parâmetro que será passado para o método.

Todos os seus métodos dentro da classe adicione o `self` como primeiro parâmetro.

Após isso na linha que dá erro é porque como você está dentro da mesma classe a forma de chamar o método que está no mesmo local (classe) é assim:

self.metodo_na_mesma_classe(parametros)

Então no seu caso ficaria:

```
#leitura de arquivo
def le(self,arquivo):
    objeto = self.existe(arquivo)
```

Lembrando que se o método `existe` gera uma exceção em caso de erro, no método `le` deve usar um `try` para capturar o erro gerado.

Comment: Obrigado, eu tava me batendo nisso desde ontem por causa disso.

Na verdade o meu método le(nome) depende do método existe(arquivo) e dependia do aguarde(). Este último era somente pra dar um feedback ao usuário caso houvessem muitas linhas. 

Sua resposta resolveu o meu problema. :)

Comment: Ahh blz, dá uma olhada melhor em OO em python, tem alguns pequenos detalhes diferentes de java.

- Self
- Herança
..

Mas boa sorte ai nos estudos.

Comment: Valeu. Vou olhar. Estou estudando pelo Youtube. Tem várias playlists sobre o assunto e algumas delas em português.